# Activiti-Rest java code

Tags: rest, activiti

```html
public static void startProcessInstance(){
 String uri=REST_URI+"/runtime/process-instances";
 log.debug("Process Instance uri: "+uri);
 JSONObject my_data=new JSONObject();
 try {
  my_data.put(Config.getConfig().getProperty("name1"),Config.getConfig().getProperty("name2"));
  my_data.put(Config.getConfig().getProperty("emailId1"),Config.getConfig().getProperty("emailId2"));
  my_data.put(Config.getConfig().getProperty("reason1"),Config.getConfig().getProperty("reason2"));
  my_data.put("processDefinitionKey",Config.getConfig().getProperty("processDefinitionKey"));
Representation response=getClientResource(uri).post(my_data);
```

I am doing activiti-rest.In documentation they have not mentioned  java classes for activiti rest such as  how to deploy a process,how to start a process,how to complete a task etc.
Can someone provide the sample codes for all process of activiti  through activiti rest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST api naming convention is 1-1 with the java api.

Deploying a process definition:

- repositoryService.createDeployment.xxx
- POST `repository/deployments`

Start a process instance:

- runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByXX
- POST `runtime/process-instances`

Complete a task:

- taskService.completeTask(taskId)
- POST `runtime/tasks/{taskId}` (complete action in body)

Comment: Hi Joram thanks for your  response.yup well we can start a process instance using method POST.But i am getting stuck when trying to do with java api.Specially when i have to start a  process using variables.I am posting you my approach in the question itself.Please have a look.

Comment: The rest way of starting a process instance is documented here: http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_start_a_process_instance. Note how 'variables' is used to pass process variables.

The same in Java would be:
`Map<String,Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();`
`vars.put("var", "value");`
`runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("someKey", vars);`

Comment: Thanks Barrez for your reply.I will try the same

Comment: Hi Joram what ever you have suggested it can possible only through spring boot+rest.But i want use only spring rest to start the process using variables.Can you suggest how to do that.Lets takes the example of my posted code.

Comment: It would be the same as a regular process instance start over REST, with a body like 
{
   "processDefinitionId":"XYZ",
   "variables": [
      {
        "name":"name1",
        "value":"name2",
      }
   ]
}

Comment: That was exaclty the same i was trying to do,but getting json object error.It may be because when i am adding as my json object through my_data parameters it build json object as {"processDefinitionId":"XYZ","variable1":"value1","variable2":"value2"}.But it should be build the json object as exactly what you have posted.Then there will be no error.Please post a sample code how to achieve that one.

Comment: I have done many task successfully such as creating user,group,task in  same way only.This all was easier because whatever i have to do not need to pass as json objects along with variables.But now here exception came when i am trying to  start a process instance.Here process instance have to pass as json object along with variables.Because of that i am getting json object error.